# Reading exit status after ssh from bash script

Tags: bash

I am working on a simple script/cli that allows users to ssh to a docker container. It works in conjunction with an API that handles some security - but I'd like to make sure I also follow some good practices.

I'll attach the code below - but here is how it works.

First, the user requests ssh access. I simply call the API to this platform, which sends back a host and a secret(password). These automatically expire after 30 mins. I call ssh with the address and display the temporary password for the user.

My script is working half as expected. If the user enters the password, connects, and then exits, I call the last function - `expire_ssh_tokens`. This successfully expires the tokens/passwords.

Though if the user cancels out of the ssh prompt before submitting the password, the `expire_ssh_tokens` function is never called.

I'd love to be able to call `expire_ssh_tokens` if the user exits at any time. Thanks for the guidance and help!

Here is my current code. Specifically, look at the elif portion of the body.

```
ssh_into(){
  echo Accessing this container...
  if [ -n "$project_to_ssh_into" ]; then
    echo Going into specific project
    list_instances
  elif [ -z "$project_to_ssh_into" ]; then
    instance_id=$(list_instances | jq '.data' | jq '.[0]' | jq -r '.id')
    ssh_credentials=$(fetch_ssh_credentials "$container_id" "$instance_id" | jq '.data')
    ssh_address_port=$(echo "$ssh_credentials" | jq -r '.address')
    ssh_address="${ssh_address_port%:22}"
    ssh_secret=$(echo "$ssh_credentials" | jq -r '.secret')
    echo Temporary Password: "$ssh_secret"
    ssh "$ssh_address"
    expire_ssh_tokens
  fi
}
```

The function `expire_ssh_tokens` is nothing speical, a simple curl.

```
expire_ssh_tokens() {
  echo Token count expired:
  curl https://api.cycle.io/v1/containers/"$container_id"/instances/"$instance_id"/ssh \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer '"$cycle_api_key" \
    -H 'X-Hub-Id: '"$cycle_hub_id" \
    -X DELETE \
    --silent
  echo
  echo Alert: ssh token expired.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a function in your script, e.g:

```
function cleanup()
{
   expire_ssh_tokens
}
```

Then use trap on EXIT (or other command signals, e.g. SIGINT):

```
trap cleanup EXIT
```

See more details: [linux journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-trap-command)

Comment: Yes - I read about this before posting and did try, almost exactly like that. Hmm maybe I am missing something about placement of the call. I tried calling it inside the body of the if statement above and it did not expire the tokens. I also tried calling it as early on in the program as I could and it did not expire the tokens. -- I am sure `expire_ssh_tokens` call works. -- Thanks for your response, I'd love to learn to use this call. -- In the mean time I did find another way of achieving this. I'll post it as an answer in addition to this!

Answer (score 0):

I found another way of doing this.

Normally, sshpass, is not a good idea to use as the password would exist in the commandline (from other articles I have read). This being said, I believe this will work here due to the my call to `expire_ssh_tokens`.

```
ssh_action() {
    sshpass -p "$ssh_secret" ssh "$ssh_address"
    expire_ssh_tokens
}
```

Since the credentials are not fetched until directly before the call to `ssh` pass, and they are expired directly after the ssh session, it seems this is a great solution for my project.

In addition to effectively expiring the ssh tokens in any exit case, `sshpass` will automatically log the user in. I no longer will have to echo the password to the user, call the standard `ssh` function, and have copy and paste the password for access.

Here is my final code!

```
ssh_into() {
  #Check to make sure container id exists
  if [ -z "$container_id" ]; then
    echo No container id found. Please provide a container id or make sure the init file exists.
    echo
    echo Usage: bicycle ssh [container_id]
    printf "${fmt_help}" \
      "From Project Directory:" "bicycle ssh" \
      "With Custom Container Id:" "bicycle ssh [container_id]"
    exit 
  fi

  #Get all instances and number of instances
  instances=$(list_instances "$container_id" | jq '.data' )
  instance_length=$(echo "$instances" | jq length )
  
  #Prompt user to choose the instance to ssh into.
  echo Instances available: "$instance_length"
  echo Choose which instance to ssh into. 
  read instance_choice

  #Subtract 1 from their choice to match the array index.
  choice=$(( $instance_choice - 1 ))
  if [ "$instance_choice" -lt "$instance_length" ]; then
    instance_id=$(echo "$instances" | jq '.['"$choice"']' | jq -r '.id')
  fi

  #Fetch the ssh credentials using the id of the choice.
  ssh_credentials=$(fetch_ssh_credentials "$container_id" "$instance_id" | jq '.data')
  ssh_address_port=$(echo "$ssh_credentials" | jq -r '.address')
  ssh_address="${ssh_address_port%:22}"
  ssh_secret=$(echo "$ssh_credentials" | jq -r '.secret')

  #Init ssh session
  sshpass -p "$ssh_secret" ssh "$ssh_address"

  #Expire tokens upon exit
  expire_ssh_tokens

}
```